# Introductory Reference for Supergravity

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, education, supergravity

I have finished quantum field theory and general relativity and want to read about supergravity. I have read about supersymmetry from the demystify series and the supersymmetry part of Wess and Bagger's Supersymmetry and Supergravity. However, I find the supergravity part of Wess's book difficult. I have also try Freedman's Supergravity, which is also a little bit hard to me. Are there any other beginner friendly introductory books on supergravity?

Comment: *beginner friendly* Beginning from what? Familiarity with graduate-level quantum field theory and General Relativity?

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, I have background on graduate level QFT and GR

Comment: Comments often get deleted, so I recommend explaining what you mean by “beginner” in the question.